# WYSIWYG for HTML of android TextView

Tags: android, textview, wysiwyg

Is there WYSIWYG for HTML elements supported in Android TextView. I am creating browser based administration for Android application but cant find WYSIWYG to create content which will be published in TextView element with support for HTML tags. If there are alternatives then share some ideas please.

Comment: i dont't know what you are trying to accomplish. But why don't use a real HTML-Editor and just copy the results to the TextView String?

Comment: @Thommy TextView allows only small set of HTML elements. You cant put for example IMG tag in. And many editors put <p> or <div> around content but I dont need that kind of behavior.